# Postgres failed to install

Tags: windows, postgresql

I'm installing PostgreSQL 10.10 on my windows 10 PC. But I'm getting the following error immediately after running the exe file.
Not sure where exactly things are going wrong. Whether it is windows user level or postgres level.
This is the installation log file...

```
Log started 08/13/2019 at 20:37:56
Preferred installation mode : qt
Trying to init installer in mode qt
Mode qt successfully initialized
Executing icacls "C:\Users\subbu\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1" /inheritance:r
Script exit code: 0
```

**Script output:**
 processed file:

```
C:\Users\subbu\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

**Script stderr:**

> Executing icacls "C:\Users\subbu\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1" /T /Q /grant "subbu:(OI)(CI)F"
>   Script exit code: 5

**Script output:**

> Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 1 files

**Script stderr:**

```
 C:\Users\subbu\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1\*: Access is denied.
```

**Error running icacls:**

> "C:\Users\subbu\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1" /T /Q /grant "subbu:(OI)(CI)F": C:\Users\subbu\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1*: Access is denied.
>   Cannot delete file C:/Users/subbu/AppData/Local/Temp/postgresql_installer_d8432abdb1

Answer (score 0):

Just run the installer again as Administrator (Right click the installer to do so).

Comment: Have done that immediately but it got failed. The error log is same.

Comment: It looks like my windows user with which I'm logged in has a problem with this particular software setup. Successfully installed with other users.

Comment: Figured out any differences between your user and the others that cause this?